# How do I assign values from Ajax to an array?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

My code is supposed to pass 'seventythree' to php where it will be sent to a MYSQL database and a calculation will be made to calculate efficiency according to the values retrieved from the table seventythree. Afterwards, it's supposed to run again and get the values from seventy four. I used a for loop for this but the result just sends the same value for both the positions 0 and 1 in the array.

```
function calculateEfficiency(){
    for (x =0; x < 2; x++){
        var y = x+1;
        switch(y){
            case 1:
                mod = "seventythree";
                break;
            case 2:
                mod = "seventyfour";
                break;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'efficiency.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'mod' : mod},
            error: function(){alert("fail");}
        }).done(function(data){
            efficiency = data.efficiency;
            refresh = data.refresh;
        }); 

        efficiencyArray[x] = efficiency;

        if (refresh){

        document.getElementById("efficiency1").innerHTML = efficiencyArray[0];
        document.getElementById("efficiency2").innerHTML = efficiencyArray[1];

        }
    }
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Everything that depends on the returned value has to be in the `.done()` function. The code after `$.ajax()` will be executed before you assign to the variables.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @barmar is saying is that you need to place this:

```
efficiencyArray[x] = efficiency;

    if (refresh){

    document.getElementById("efficiency1").innerHTML = efficiencyArray[0];
    document.getElementById("efficiency2").innerHTML = efficiencyArray[1];

    }
```

Inside of this:

```
.done(function(data){
//inside here
});
```

Comment: This results in the two values of the array becoming undefined. The values are passing from the php but there seems to be an error in efficiencyArray[x] = efficiency;

Comment: check what the server is returning. add this inside of the `done` function and check your console: `console.log(data);`

Comment: @DaveHowson if `efficiency` is an array, there is no need to pass it to `efficiencyArray`, you can just call it like so: `efficiency[0]`

Comment: The values from the server pass without issue. The issue seems to be with the x inside efficiencyArray[x]. When replacing this with 0, I get the first efficiency value.

Comment: get rid of the x. you are passing x as a variable when x doesnt even exist. just use `efficiency` and don't pass it to `efficiencyArray[x]`. delete that line

Comment: @DaveHowson oh nvm so you're calling it from inside the loop and x is the number inside the loop.

Comment: `.done(function(data){
    efficiency[0] = data.efficiency;
    alert(x);
    refresh = data.refresh;
   
    if (refresh){
     

    document.getElementById("efficiency1").innerHTML = efficiency[0];
    document.getElementById("efficiency2").innerHTML = efficiency[1];
   
   }
   }); `
This is how it is now but this only assigns the first efficiency, which is why I used x, so when it increases, the next efficiency value will be assigned

Comment: what does `console.log(efficiencyArray);` say? place it after you create the `efficiencyArray`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146096/discussion-between-dave-howson-and-josan-iracheta).